# How do I code-sign an executable created by a python wheel?

Tags: python, setuptools, code-signing, python-wheel

I'm creating a python package with an executable as a wheel using setuptools. My simplified `setup.py` file looks like this:

```py
setup(
    name="mypackage",
    version="1.0.0",
    entry_points={"console_scripts": {"mypackage = mypackage.cli:cli"}}
)
```

Command to create the python package:

```
python setup.py bdist_wheel
```

When installing the resulting wheel, a `mypackage.exe` file is created in the scripts directory as expected.

**How can I make sure, that the created executable is code-signed with a given certificate?** I know how to code sign an *existing* executable using `signtool.exe` or Powershell, but since the executable seems to be created on the client machine when the wheel is installed, I don't know how to do it.

Comment: AFAIK this isn't supported by the wheel spec, so I doubt it's doable. Maybe precreating the signed executable and packaging it via the `scripts` keyword? But then again, IIRC you can't package binaries via `scripts`, so you'll need some `distutils` magic to avoid that first (custom packaging command etc)